# How to switch to integrated graphics card on HP G62-b40EM?

Tags: integrated-graphics, intel-core-i3

I have a HP G62-b40EM laptop with Intel Core i3 350M and ATI/AMD Radeon HD 5470. How do I enable the integrated graphics card? Official Intel page says, that the processor has an IGP, but I can't seem to figure out how to enable it.

Even HP support page has drivers for both cards listed, but when I try to install Intel driver, I get an error:

> This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing this software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can change the default switchable graphics settings with the ATI Catalyst Control Center software installed on your HP notebook PC. (If you do not have this software, or if you previously uninstalled it, see HP Notebook PCs - Locate and Install Updated BIOS, Drivers, and Software to learn how get the latest version.)
>   If you want to maximize the notebook's energy efficiency or if you typically use programs that have slight graphical requirements (such as word processing or spreadsheet programs), you do not need to make any changes to the settings in the ATI Catalyst Control Center. The notebook will use the power-saving chipset by default for all applications. You can still run high performance programs, videos and games in this mode but you may notice lower frame rates, dropped frames, and choppy animations and transitions.
>   If you use applications that have heavier graphical requirements (such as 3D video games), then you can try using the high-performance chipset for those applications . This allows graphics intensive software, videos and games to run at their optimum settings.
>
> To change the switchable graphics settings in the ATI Catalyst Control Center:
>
> Click Start , type CCC in the search field, and then select CCC - Advanced from the search results list.
>
> Select Switchable Graphics from the menu in the Catalyst Control Center.
>
> Select a Recent Application and click the green or red button to change the default graphic solution from power-saving to high-performance.
>
> Or click Browse to find the executable file for the application you need to configure.
>   Click Apply to save the new settings.
>
> The specified changes take place immediately.

[image]

> Note:
>   When configuring the Dynamic Switchable Graphics in the Catalyst Control Center, some notebook PCs may not permit any OpenGL applications to be associated with the Discrete (dGPU) or high-performance GPU. The OpenGL applications will work using the power-saving or Integrated GPU (iGPU) but the performance levels may be lower than expected. HP has released an updated BIOS and AMD Graphics driver to enable Fixed Mode Switchable Graphics functionality for certain notebook models originally configured with Dynamic Switchable Graphics.

[Source Of Information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02731962&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en)

Comment: I don't have the "Switchable Graphics" page in my Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: Try installing this HP driver, see if it enables that function....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-93513-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=5036288&sw_lang=

Comment: I installed it, but it's still disabled.

Comment: Install the Intel driver and reboot...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-91877-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=5036288&sw_lang=

Comment: I tried, as I said in the question, but it says that my computer does not meet the minimum requirements.

Comment: All that is left is to use HP recovery manager to restore the PC to factory state, back up important data before you do this, if this fails to get it working use your warranty with HP to get it repaired.